# HTACCESS.. Restrict acces xml file from out

Tags: .htaccess

I have xml file. i use it as db. how can i restrict access to this file..
i checked more than one option its worked but owner (website) also cant access this xml file..

How can i restrict acces this file from outside but the website can use this xml..

i`ve checked

```
chmod 700
```

and

```
ErrorDocument ### index.php -- Example of format 
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php -- Working example
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?site\.com(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(xml)$ - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need mod_rewrite for this:

```
<Files /db.xml>
   Order Allow, Deny
   Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: thanks for answer... this do it but owner(website) also cant access this file ((